# Как подцепить элементы? CSS

Tags: html, css

Как можно подцепить два элемента из множества с одинаковыми классами, которые не последние в родительском блоке?

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ama"></div>
  <div class="ama"></div>
  <div class="ama"></div>
  <div class="ama"></div>
  <div class="ama"></div><!-- этот блок нужно подцепить -->
  <div class="ama"></div><!-- и этот блок нужно подцепить -->
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="lalala"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит подцепить?

Comment: Обратиться к элементу средствами CSS

Comment: Вам нужны элементы с классами `example, lalala`?

Comment: нет, мне нужны последние(!) два элемента с классом `ama`

Comment: Если будет `not class ama` то можно, а так не для всего расклада можно.

Comment: типа `p:not(ama):last-child` ? Это же будет работать для всего кроме `ama`, что-то запутался...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72612/discussion-between-raz-galstyan-and--).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так можете сделать с помощью `not()` и `last-of-type`.

```css
.wrap>div:not(.ama):not(:last-of-type):not(:nth-last-of-type(2)) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <!-- этот блок нужно подцепить -->
  <div class="ama">ama</div>
  <!-- и этот блок нужно подцепить -->
  <div class="ama">и этот блок нужно подцепить</div>
  <div class="ama">и этот блок нужно подцепить</div>
  <div class="example">asasdasd</div>
  <div class="lalala">asdasdasd</div>
  <div>xxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: И это правильный ответ?)))))))))))))))))))

Comment: @Air Посмотрите переписку в чате с автором вопроса

Comment: у него, что изменились планы?))))

Comment: По моему он сам не знает что ему надо))))))

Comment: @Air ну может после переписки узнал

Comment: эм, "и этот блок нужно подцепить" в итоге не подцеплен, а в случае добавления `.example` и `.lalala`, список выделения будет расширяться. Впрочем, автор вопроса действительно сам не знает, что ему нужно или осознал безысходность.

Answer (score 2):

Тогда придется именно эти элементы с данным классом обернуть в отдельный блок

```css
.ama:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>        
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama0</div>
    <div class="ama">ama1</div>
    <div class="ama">ama1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="example">rr</div>
  <div class="lalala">rr</div>
  <div>ww</div>
  <div>ww</div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно обращаться к последним двум, потому что их количество может меняться

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете привязаться к последнему и предпоследнему элементу списка таким способом:

```css
.wrap > div:last-of-type,
.wrap > div:nth-last-of-type(2){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ama">1</div>
  <div class="ama">2</div>
  <div class="ama">3</div>
  <div class="ama">4</div>
  <div class="ama">5</div>
  <div class="ama">6</div>
  <div class="example">7</div>
  <div class="lalala">8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Однако, вы не можете его использовать для конкретного класса. Только для определенного типа. То же касается и `nth-last-child`. При помощи JS вопрос решается быстро.

Comment: Перечитай вопрос внимательней....

Comment: Я поэтому и написал, что он не может использовать его для конкретного класса. В тег у него тоже не обернуты элементы. На CSS эту задачку вряд ли можно решить.

Comment: Блин, вообще, согласись, хрень какая та...  По логике  `.omo:nth-last-of-type(-n + 2)`  должен именно элементы классом `omo`  подхватить

Comment: По логике - да, ведь привязываться к конкретным элементам он может, к диапазонам - может. А выделить последний из классов - не может.